# Server 2012 indexing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, imap, indexing, outlook-2013, indexing-service

we are encountering an issue where an Index file keeps growing indefinite until the special partition for it becomes full and causes it to be come corrupted, which the indexer then deletes and rebuilds.

From my understanding the indexing file should not really go over 100gb, but this cycle continues month after month and increases to around ~350GB.

This is a remote desktop server where all of an office works and relies on the searching service to search for emails in outlook so disabling is not an option.

Emails are done through IMAP and hosted on the same server. Only certain folders are being indexed (data folders etc)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add more discs.

You decided to go with a quite unusual setup (IMAP instead of exchange, all running on a terminal server) - now you have to pay the price, which obviously includes having more disc space.

Comment: This is a really unhelpful answer, we can increase the disk space for the indexing but it looks like it will grow indefinitely, so this would only be a temporary solution. Normally we would go for Exchange, but the customer does not like spending money unfortunately (was not my decision anyway).